# Registry Form appears blank?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm creating a data base for my company, and I'm trying to make it very simple for my colleagues. I created a registry form that has some buttons to go to search forms (I created 2 different forms to locate different things) but the code that I found doesn't allow to modify the registry when I double click.  The code is this:

```
   DoCmd.OpenForm "Registo", acNormal, "", "[ID]= [Forms]![PesquisaPorNome]![ListaNomes]", acFormPropertySetting, acWindowNormal
   DoCmd.Close acForm, "PesquisaPorNomes"
```

It was supposed to open my registry form and put the names and other information on the form, but it appears blank.
I don't know if it's the code or if it's the forms that aren't correct for the code to work.

I hope someone can help me.

I'm sorry for my bad English, it isn't my first language.

Comment: Code works for me. Is ListaNomes a listbox? Are you sure its value is ID?

Comment: Yes, ListaNomes is a listbox and I'm sure the value is ID. I even change it to other things that I had and it's the same thing

Comment: Cannot replicate issue. Would have to review db and SO doesn't not allow attaching files. There are other forums that do.